# Will my Schengen visa application automatically be denied if my resident permit is going to expire within 3 months?

Tags: schengen

I just want to ask. I have an upcoming trip to the Czech Republic and Austria on the 1st-7th November. I am going to apply for a single entry schengen visa. The problem is that my IRP is going to expire on the 3rd of January which puts it within the 3 month allowance for a residence card before expiration. The local GARDA will only allow it to be renewed within 1 month of the expiration. I contacted the Czech embassy and the reply I received was "There is a possibility that you may be able to apply with your GNIB card if you have all the documentation without any other problems". I want to ask, will they automatically refuse my application because of this scenario?

Comment: Who do you believe more, the person working at the Czech embassy or a person on internet who may know what he is talking about or may not know what he is talking about?

Comment: As of now, I really don't know. People working in the embassy can have different principles. The one who made that reply may not have the same response with another worker in the embassy.

Comment: I am a bit apprehensive to apply, but I already have everything planned for that dates.

Comment: Make sure you have all details you can get together, all paperwork for staying in Ireland and proof for continued living there if you can, and hope for the best.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there's no formal limitation on when you're allowed to renew your IRP, and your local Garda station is extremely unlikely to take issue with you doing it early if you explain the situation to them. You've still got plenty of time, so I'd suggest applying for a visa with the card and documentation you have (make sure to include the documentation that got you the IRP in the first place!), and if you do get denied, take the denial letter with you to an early IRP renewal appointment.

Note that your local Garda station is likely to be less experienced and knowledgeable about the IRP process than INIS (which manages registration for people in Dublin). If you do end up having to renew early, a printed-out email response from INIS saying that that's allowed could make the process smoother.

Comment: we already asked the local GARDA station here and they wont allow it to be renewed as early as December.

Comment: If that was just their default response to "can I renew way early", then they might change their mind if they understood the full situation and saw the denial letter and confirmation from INIS that it's not prohibited.

Comment: And while I'm not going to suggest any dishonest course of action, if one were to *lose* one's IRP card, the issue of early renewal wouldn't be relevant.....